# Fix possible file path in tkinter File dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frontend

I'm creating a user interface with tkinter and i'm using the function below to pick a filename from the system.

```
self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "./TEST/", title = "Select a File", filetypes = (("Text files","*.txt*"), ("all files","*.*")))
```

The generated windows allows to do that, but everything can be selected. I want to block the possibility given to the user to use files outside of the local folder, there is a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easy enough to *verify* that the user chose a file in the starting folder (compare the `os.path.dirname()` of the file to the initialdir), but there's no way for the file dialog itself to enforce that.